# FullCalendar event color to qtip

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, qtip

I'm using the fullcalendar and qtip plugins.
I have events with different colors.
All I need to do is to have a tooltip that correspond to the colors of full calendar event.
I want the qtip(tooltip) color change depending on the event color.
Is that possible?
Thanks.. :)

[image]

here are the codes for my qtip

```
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: {
                title: { text: event.title },
                text: '<span class="title" style="font-weight:bold;">Start: </span>' + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'hh:mmtt')) +
                    '<br><span class="title" style="font-weight:bold;">End: </span>' + ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'hh:mmtt')) +
                    '<br><span class="title" style="font-weight:bold;">Where: </span>' + event.location +
                    '<br><span class="title" style="font-weight:bold;">Description: </span>' + event.description
            },
            position: {
                adjust: { screen: true },
                corner: { target: 'bottomMiddle', tooltip: 'topLeft' }
            },
            show: {
                solo: true, effect: { type: 'slide' }, effect: function () {
                    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.8);
                }
            },
            hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true },
            style: {
                tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip
                border: {
                    width: 2,
                    radius: 5,
                    color: '#474968'

                },
                title: {
                    color: '#fff',
                    background: '#9193c4'
                },
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How are you setting the event colour? If you are using a custom attribute then you can use this in your event render callback to colour the element

Comment: I just set the event colors for holidays in event sources.. and for the new added event-I set the color in css

Comment: .fc-event-skin {
 border-color: #9193c4; background-color: #9193c4; color: #fff;  
 }

Answer (score 0):

The event object accepts a [className](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) attribute. You can use this to colour your events using CSS (for example applying a "holiday" class). Within your eventRender callback you can then check for the presence of this class ( if (event.className === 'holiday') ... ) and colour your tooltip appropriately